# .map json from prisma in component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma

I'm trying to map a json object in a nextjs class component with data coming from prisma. I stringify the data coming from prisma, else I get a serialization error on the date parameter.

I understand I cannot .map this.props.comments2, but how do I achieve what I am trying to do in the correct way?

Getting data:

**Index.tsx:**

```
export default function Home({ comments2 }) {
...
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  console.log("lol");
  const comments = await prisma.casinoComment.findMany();
  const comments2 = JSON.stringify(comments);
  console.log(comments2);
  return { props: { comments2 } };
}
```

**Component/List.tsx:**

```
interface IProps {
  comments2: [
    {
      content: string;
    }
  ];
}

export default class FeaturedCasinos extends React.Component<
  IProps,
  IState,
  { country: String; flag: String }
> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return {
    <>
      {this.props.comments2.map((comment, index) => {
        comment.content;
       })}
    </>
    }
  }
  ...
  }
```

**Json object:**

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "casinoId": 1,
    "content": "test",
    "reply": false,
    "parentId": 0,
    "approved": false,
    "likes": 3,
    "createdAt": "2021-11-21T19:47:56.387Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-11-21T19:47:56.387Z",
    "authorId": "ckw87a0r50008hvpvas31ow8k"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "casinoId": 1,
    "content": "test",
    "reply": false,
    "parentId": 0,
    "approved": false,
    "likes": 3,
    "createdAt": "2021-11-21T19:52:07.427Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-11-21T19:52:07.427Z",
    "authorId": "ckw87a0r50008hvpvas31ow8k"
  }
]
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? i am confused

Comment: Just .map/output the json object in comments2, in the component.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% on your question but from the looks of it just change your jsx

This

```
    <>
      {this.props.comments2.map((comment, index) => {
        comment.content;
       })}
    </>
```

to this

```
    <>
      {this.props.comments2.map((comment, index) => {
         return(
           <p>comment.content</p>
         )
       })}
    </>
```

Comment: I tried it but it returns: TypeError: this.props.comments2.map is not a function... I suspected since I stringified "comment", I lost the object properties so I cannot use .map, but Im not sure

Comment: @CultofTranquility did you console log the `comments2` array inside the component?

Comment: yes, it appears to be there, but its just seem to be a string with the json, not an array or object with .map property.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it...

Solution was to JSON.parse the comments after stringifying them:

```
  const comments = await prisma.casinoComment.findMany();

  const comments2 = JSON.stringify(comments);
  const parsedComments = JSON.parse(comments2);
```

after this .map worked in the component, since you cant .map a pure string (which is not an array or object with the .map property)...